# Why std::make_unique calls copy constructor

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, deep-copy

I'm wondering why make_unique calls copy constructor but does not call default constructor.

```cpp
Node()
{
    std::cout << "default";
}

~Node(){
    std::cout << " Delete";
}

Node(const Node& other ){
    std::cout << "copy";
}

int main(){
    Node<int,int,int,int> test1; //Calling default Cons
    std::unique_ptr<Node<int,int,int,int>> test2  = 
                               std::make_unique<Node<int,int,int,int>>(test1);//Nothing called

    Node<int,int,int,int> *test3 = test2.get();
    Node<int,int,int,int> test4 = Node<int,int,int,int>(*test3);// Calling copy Cons

    std::unique_ptr<Node<int,int,int,int>> test5 = 
                            std::make_unique<Node<int,int,int,int>(test4);//Calling copy Cons
}
```

For example in code shown above:
Frist, we create Node object -> calling default constructor.
Then we wrap this object into smart-pointer object -> no calls.

But if we make deep copy of Node object -> calling copy constructor
And then wrap copy into smart-pointer object-> calling copy constructor.

It's somehow connected to the creation of new control block?

Comment: Got 1 default and 3 copies as expected [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2826195f92025295).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<Node<int,int,int,int>> test5 = 
   std::make_unique<Node<int,int,int,int>(test4);// You copy from test4
```

`std::make_unique` creates a *new* pointer. It doesn't reuse an existing pointer.
So since test4 is already there, it has to copy it. After test5 is constructed, test4 is still there (so can't do a move) and test5 is holding a new object, copied from test4.

Comment: Thank you, while wrapping test1 copy constructor is also called, I overlooked it.