# Why an extra set of constructor/destructor call for std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

Looks like std::make_unique is making extra copy(related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019871/why-stdmake-unique-calls-copy-constructor)) while it is supposed to be more efficient. Below is a sample implementation with typical c++ polymorphic class architecture. The output mentioned below the code snippet shows if we uncomment the call to make_unique, it calls an extra pair of ctor/dtor.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    Shape() { cout << "Shape::ctor\n"; }
    virtual ~Shape() {cout << "Shape::dtor\n";}
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    Rectangle() {cout << "Rectangle::ctor\n";}
    virtual ~Rectangle() {cout << "Rectangle::dtor\n";}
};

unique_ptr<Shape> makeShape(int type) 
{
    //unique_ptr<Shape> spShape = make_unique<Shape>(); //extra ctor call
    unique_ptr<Shape> spShape(nullptr);
    switch (type)
    {
    case 1: //rect
        spShape.reset(new Rectangle());
        break;   
    default:
        break;
    }
    return spShape;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto shape1 = makeShape(1);
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> ==========================
> output with make_unique
> --------------------------
> Shape::ctor
> Shape::ctor
> Rectangle::ctor
> Shape::dtor
> Rectangle::dtor
> Shape::dtor
> --------------------------
> output w/o make_unique
> --------------------------
> Shape::ctor
> Rectangle::ctor
> Rectangle::dtor
> Shape::dtor
> --------------------------
> ```

make_unique doesn't works with custom deleter. So what is benefit of using it?

Comment: If you just want an empty `unique_ptr`, then just `unique_ptr<Shape> spShape;` is enough. I don't really understand why you give it the `nullptr` argument or try to use `make_unique`. Or do you expect the pointer to point to a `Shape` object in the default case?

Comment: *"Looks like std::make_unique is making extra copy(related post) while it is supposed to be more efficient."* -- more efficient than what? Your code compares calling `make_unique`, which constructs a `Shape` object, to using `nullptr`, which does not. Of course there is an extra constructor call when you construct an extra object. Why did you think otherwise?

Answer (score 5):

The `std::make_unique<Shape>()` does not create a null `unique_ptr`. Instead, it is equivalent to this:

```cpp
unique_ptr<Shape> makeShape(int type) 
{
    unique_ptr<Shape> spShape(new Shape); //extra ctor call
    switch (type)
    {
    case 1: //rect
        // Must destroy old spShape here.
        spShape.reset(new Rectangle());
        break;   
    default:
        break;
    }
    return spShape;
}
```

If you don’t want to create an object, don't use `std::make_unique`. The purpose of `std::make_unique` is to construct the object and make the `std::unique_ptr` in one step.

> [make_unique] is supposed to be more efficient [...]

No, it is not. It is supposed to be safer, if you are constructing objects with temporaries. See:

[Differences between std::make_unique and std::unique_ptr with new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571202/differences-between-stdmake-unique-and-stdunique-ptr-with-new)

### Cleaned-up code:

I might write it this way:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Shape> makeShape(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case 1:
        return std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
    default:
        return std::make_unique<Shape>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> std::make_unique ... while it is supposed to be more efficient

`std::make_unique` isn't "supposed to be more efficient". It's a safe and convenient way to create objects in dynamic storage.

> Looks like std::make_unique is making extra copy

It's because you're using it wrong. Do this:

```
switch (type)
{
    case 1: // sidenote: don't use magic numbers such as this
        return std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
    default:
        return nullptr;
}
```

> what is benefit of using it?

Some benefits of using `std::make_unique<T>()` versus using `std::unique_ptr(some_bare_owning_pointer)` are:

- Exception safety. If exception is thrown after memory was allocated, but before the constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is entered, then you leak the allocation. There are cases where this doesn't look possible to happen, but it subtly is (especially prior to C++17).
- It lets you follow the rules of thumb "write one delete for each new" (write 0 news -> write 0 deletes) as well as "never use an owning bare pointer".